# Редактирование и настройка почтовых заголовков (mail headers) в Python

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, header

Добрый день! Мне необходимо для тестирования системы периодически отправлять и получать специальные письма с различными заголовками. Для реализации этой задачи я использую smtplib и MIMEText с энкодером encode_quopri.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.encoders import encode_quopri

SERVER = 'mailserver.loc'
FROM = 'sender@' + SERVER
TO = 'abonent1@' + SERVER

msg = MIMEText('проверка проверка проверка', 'plain', _charset='windows-1251')
msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
msg['From'] = FROM
msg['To'] = TO
msg['X-Message-id'] = 'xmsg_id'
encode_quopri(msg)

print (msg)
```

На выходе получаю:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="windows-1251"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Subject: subject
From: sender@mailserver.loc
To: abonent1@mailserver.loc
X-Message-id: xmsg_id
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=EF=F0=EE=E2=E5=F0=EA=E0=20=EF=F0=EE=E2=E5=F0=EA=E0=20=EF=F0=EE=E2=E5=F0=EA=
=E0
```

Но у меня задвоился заголовок:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
...
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Я попробовал удалить первый, но тогда ломается quoted-printable и результат:

```
7/Du4uXw6uAg7/Du4uXw6uAg7/Du4uXw6uA=3D
```

Моя цель получить вот такой заголовок:

```
Date: Wed, 1 Jun 2011 11:25:32 +0400
From: Billinfo <billing@mailserver.loc>
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <878185321.20110601112532>
To: abonent1@mailserver.loc
Subject: Just a subject
Resent-from: Billinfo <billing@mailserver.loc>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="----------115EA32B5A1C2"
Resent-Message-Id: <20110601072537.A8F1A3C14A>
Resent-Date: Wed,  1 Jun 2011 11:25:37 +0400 (MSD)

------------115EA32B5A1C2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=EF=F0=EE=E2=E5=F0=EA=E0=20=EF=F0=EE=E2=E5=F0=EA=E0=20=EF=F0=EE=E2=E5=F0=EA=
=E0
------------115EA32B5A1C2
Content-Type: APPLICATION/VND.MS-EXCEL;
 name="doc.xls"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="doc.xls"

some base64 content
------------115EA32B5A1C2--
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь в решении моего вопроса!

**UPD 11/04/2015:**
Моё решение:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.charset import Charset
from email.encoders import encode_quopri

SERVER = 'mailserver.loc'
FROM = 'billing@' + SERVER
TO = 'abonent1@' + SERVER

msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
msg['From'] = FROM
msg['To'] = TO
msg['X-Message-id'] = 'xmsg_id'


charset = Charset('windows-1251')

att1 = MIMEText('проверка111 проверка проверка', 'plain', _charset=None)
encode_quopri(att1)
att1.set_charset(charset)
del att1['Content-Transfer-Encoding']
del att1['MIME-Version']
att1['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'quoted-printable'


msg.attach(att1)

print (msg.as_string())

################### OUTPUT ###################
# Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============2009055196=="
# MIME-Version: 1.0
# Subject: subject
# From: billing@mailserver.loc
# To: abonent1@mailserver.loc
# X-Message-id: xmsg_id

# --===============2009055196==
# Content-Type: text/plain; charset="windows-1251"
# Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

# =D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=BA=D0=B0111=20=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=
# =B2=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=BA=D0=B0=20=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=BA=D0=
# =B0
# --===============2009055196==--
```

Благодарю за помощь! Заголовки нормально воспринимаются принимающей программой и письмо корректно обрабатывается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы желаете получить — составное письмо. 
Его составляющие: 1. текст; 2. файл-вложение.

Поэтому при формировании письма следует использовать тип **MIMEMultipart**, который будет играть роль оболочки для его частей (именно ему следует присваивать заголовки, которые вы присваиваете MIMEText).

Далее к оболочке нужно будет прикрепить (метод *attach*) объекты типов **MIMEText** (ваш текст), и **MIMEApplication** (ваш файл-вложение).

Comment: Пока удалось получить вот такое: http://pastebin.com/uNkPiLK9
Код: http://pastebin.com/GT9uFAyw
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от двойного заголовка и удалить _Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64_?

Если можно, с примером.
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: @StanislavAmelin base64 проставляется автоматически, однако, это можно контролировать, если передать _charset=None (вы же передаёте windows-1251). И *encode_quopri* и *set_charset* нужно применить не к объекту-оболочке, а к MIMEText.

Comment: прошу прощения, не понял выражение "encode_quopri применить к MIMEText". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать? Вот что на сейчас есть: http://pastebin.com/wMJAgCb2 Можно ли как-то контролировать `MIME-Version: 1.0` в MIMEText?

Comment: Всё верно делаете, только сначала *encode_quopri*, а потом нужную кодировку. Касательно заголовка с версией mime: это стандартное поведение MIMEBase, удалить можно обычной инструкцией **del** - del att1['MIME-Version'].

Comment: Благодарю! Пока ещё не знал про инструкцию del. А вот с объявлением _encode_quopri_ не получилось: http://pastebin.com/uANDKqE0 Всё равно два заголовка.

Comment: Из интереса проверил ваш код, у меня выдаётся с одним заголовком. Впрочем, теперь, когда вы знаете не только как добавлять заголовки, но и как их удалять - дело за малым %) Обладая этими знаниями вы можете управлять наличием тех или иных заголовков в тех или иных частях писем.

Comment: Огромная благодарка! Решил вот так: http://pastebin.com/j6CTt6CB

Comment: А на какой версии вы проверяли, можете уточнить, пожалуйста? У меня установлена 3.4.1.

Comment: Хорошо, что всё срослось %) 2.7.8